# Data not inserted into mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm on my local Ubunto machine and following a tutorial to learn node/mongodb. Here is the code:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp', (err, db) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server');
  }
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB server');

  db.collection('Todos').insertOne({
    text: 'Something to do',
    completed: false
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to insert todo', err);
    }

    console.log('data inserted');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops, undefined, 2));
  });

  db.close();
});
```

My driver version: `"mongodb": "^2.2.5"`
My mongodb version `v3.2.20`

I can see `Connected to MongoDB server` is being printed out but I don't get the result json in the terminal, nor the `data inserted` alert. What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: post the code for schema as well

Comment: There is no scheme. It's all the code that there is.

Comment: @narad I see an exception, when `close()` is called this way, don't you see it?

Comment: `Connected to MongoDB server
Unable to insert todo { MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed`

Answer (score 2):

I think you close connection too early, try to move `close()` into `insertOne` callback:

```
console.log('data inserted');
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.ops, undefined, 2));
db.close();
```

Comment: Makes no difference.

Comment: even move `close` to the bottom?

Comment: Actually, my code is correct. i was running the wrong script though. sorry!

Comment: Please remove your anser so that I can remove the stupid question